# Suggestion error with Coveo search box

Tags: coveo

Anyone know what could be causing this? I'm implementing a field suggest on a CoveoSearchBox and when I test the suggest on every char I enter it is calling the rest call and it shows a JS error.

Here is the url it tries to access:

http://sitecore81/coveo/rest/v2/values?sitecoreItemUri=sitecore%3A%2F%2Fmaster%2F%7B110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9%7D%3Flang%3Den%26ver%3D1&siteName=website

```json
"statusCode" : 400,
"message" : "The parameter is missing: field",
"type" : "MissingParameterException",
"executionReport" : [ {
    "children" : [ {
      "description" : "Perform authentication",
      "duration" : 1,
      "configured" : {
        "trust" : null,
        "primary" : [ "SearchToken", "Windows" ],
        "secondary" : [ ],
        "admin" : "NobodyAllowed",
        "fallback" : null,
        "mandatory" : [ ]
  },
```

Here is how my searchbox is defined:

```html
<div class="CoveoSearchbox form-control"
     data-auto-focus="@Model.AutoFocus"
     data-enable-lowercase-operators="@Model.EnableLowercaseOperators"
     data-enable-partial-match="@Model.EnablePartialMatch"
     data-partial-match-keywords="@Model.PartialMatchKeywords"
     data-partial-match-threshold="@Model.PartialMatchThreshold"
     data-enable-question-marks="@Model.EnableQuestionMarks"
     data-enable-wildcards="@Model.EnableWildcards"
     data-enable-omnibox="true"
     data-omnibox-timeout="@Model.OmniboxTimeout"
     data-enable-field-addon="@Model.OmniboxEnableFieldAddon"
     data-enable-simple-field-addon="@Model.OmniboxEnableSimpleFieldAddon"
     data-enable-top-query-addon="@Model.OmniboxEnableTopQueryAddon"
     data-enable-reveal-query-suggest-addon="@Model.OmniboxEnableRevealQuerySuggestAddon"
     data-enable-query-extension-addon="@Model.OmniboxEnableQueryExtensionAddon">
    <span class="CoveoFieldSuggestions" data-header-title="Results" data-field="@Model.ToCoveoFieldName("title")"></span>          
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is it possible that the title field is not a facet?

According to [developers.coveo.com/display/SitecoreV4/Provide+Query+Suggestions](https://developers.coveo.com/x/BoIUAg):
- The field used for suggestions needs to be a facet field

Comment: I knew I was missing something simple :) that was it. thanks Simon!

Comment: @SLangevin Can you expand on the answer by providing a link etc please.

Comment: @flguillemette was nice enough to do it for me :)